# How can I fix my JS slot machine - checkbox error

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

So i want to make a slot machine game, and when the user is pressing the Number checkbox he will play with numbers, and if he press the Image button he will play with images. But when i choice numbers and after images and after i come back to numbers the game REMAINS to images. How can i fix this. You can see a demo here:

```js
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const message = document.querySelector('.message');
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.check');
const numbers = document.querySelector('#numbers');
const images = document.querySelector('#images');

numbers.addEventListener('change', function (){
    button.addEventListener('click', randomNumbers);


  });

images.addEventListener('change', function (){
  button.addEventListener('click', randomNumbers2);

  });



function randomNumbers() {

    let arr = [];
    for (number of card){
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        number.innerHTML = random;
        arr.push(number.textContent);   
    }
    //transforming the array into array of card
    let arr2 = arr.map(function(num) {
        return parseInt(num, 10);
      });
   
    const allEqual = arr => arr.every( num => num === arr[0] )
    if(allEqual(arr2)){
        result = message.innerHTML = "YOU WON!";
        message.classList.remove("lost");
        message.classList.add("won"); 
    }else{
        result = message.innerHTML = "YOU LOST!";
        message.classList.add("lost");
        message.classList.remove("won");
    }
    
}




function randomNumbers2() {

  let arr3 = [];

  for (number of card){

    let img_arr = ['https://img1.looper.com/img/gallery/captain-americas-mcu-story-explained/intro-1566320977.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/2QFZ9Ld.jpg', 'https://images.alphacoders.com/102/thumb-1920-1026220.jpg']
   
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    let img =  '<img src="' +img_arr[random] + '" alt = "">';
    number.innerHTML = img
    arr3.push(number.innerHTML);   
    

}
const allEqual = arr => arr.every( num => num === arr[0] )
    if(allEqual(arr3)){
        result = message.innerHTML = "YOU WON!";
        message.classList.remove("lost");
        message.classList.add("won"); 
    }else{
        result = message.innerHTML = "YOU LOST!";
        message.classList.add("lost");
        message.classList.remove("won");
    }
    
  
}
checkboxes.forEach(input => { 
  input.addEventListener('click',function (){
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
      //uncheck all
      if(checkboxes[i].checked == true){
        checkboxes[i].checked = false;
      }
    }
    //set checked of clicked object
    if(input.checked == true){
      input.checked = false;
    }else{
      input.checked = true;
    } 
  })
})
```

```css
.container{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.card{
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border: 1px solid rgb(206, 21, 21);
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
}
.board{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.board button {
    padding: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(0, 162, 255);
    color: whitesmoke;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.message{
    text-align: center;
    top: 20%;
}

.lost{
    color: red;
}

.won{
    color: green;
}

form{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

form  label{
    margin-right: 15px;
}

img{
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <form>
          <label>
            <input class="check" id="numbers" type="checkbox" >    Numbers
          </label>
          <label>
            <input class="check" id="images" type="checkbox" > Images
          </label>
      
      </form>  
        <div class="board">
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <button class="button">Play</button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="message"></h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addEventListener()` does not remove (or replace) the existing event handlers on an element. You could modify the button's `onClick` attribute instead of using `addEventListener()` (there can only be one `onClick`) or you can remove the button's existing event listener before adding another. The code below uses the second approach.

I've also changed the checkboxes to radio buttons, since only one option can be chosen at a time. This removes the need for another event handler just to toggle the checkboxes.

This is just a slight modification to what you already have. Ideally, you would have a single event handler attached to the button that would check the state of the radio buttons and call the image or number routine. **Edit: added a second example below**

#### Example 1: Remove event listener before adding new one

```js
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const message = document.querySelector('.message');
const numbers = document.querySelector('#numbers');
const images = document.querySelector('#images');

// Changed the two functions below
numbers.addEventListener('change', function (){
    if (numbers.checked) {
       button.removeEventListener('click', randomNumbers2);
       button.addEventListener('click', randomNumbers);
    }
 });
images.addEventListener('change', function (){
    if (images.checked) {
       button.removeEventListener('click', randomNumbers);
       button.addEventListener('click', randomNumbers2);
    }
});


function randomNumbers() {
    let arr = [];
    for (number of card){
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        number.innerHTML = random;
        arr.push(number.textContent);   
    }
    //transforming the array into array of card
    let arr2 = arr.map(function(num) {
        return parseInt(num, 10);
      });
   
    const allEqual = arr => arr.every( num => num === arr[0] )
    if(allEqual(arr2)){
        result = message.innerHTML = "YOU WON!";
        message.classList.remove("lost");
        message.classList.add("won"); 
    }else{
        result = message.innerHTML = "YOU LOST!";
        message.classList.add("lost");
        message.classList.remove("won");
    }
    
}


function randomNumbers2() {
  let arr3 = [];

  for (number of card){
    let img_arr = ['https://img1.looper.com/img/gallery/captain-americas-mcu-story-explained/intro-1566320977.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/2QFZ9Ld.jpg', 'https://images.alphacoders.com/102/thumb-1920-1026220.jpg']
   
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    let img =  '<img src="' +img_arr[random] + '" alt = "">';
    number.innerHTML = img
    arr3.push(number.innerHTML);   
}

const allEqual = arr => arr.every( num => num === arr[0] )
    if(allEqual(arr3)){
        result = message.innerHTML = "YOU WON!";
        message.classList.remove("lost");
        message.classList.add("won"); 
    }else{
        result = message.innerHTML = "YOU LOST!";
        message.classList.add("lost");
        message.classList.remove("won");
    }
}
```

```css
.container{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.card{
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border: 1px solid rgb(206, 21, 21);
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
}
.board{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.board button {
    padding: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(0, 162, 255);
    color: whitesmoke;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.message{
    text-align: center;
    top: 20%;
}

.lost{
    color: red;
}

.won{
    color: green;
}

form{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

form  label{
    margin-right: 15px;
}

img{
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <form>
          <label>
            <input class="check" id="numbers" type="radio" name="game">Numbers
          </label>
          <label>
            <input class="check" id="images" type="radio" name="game">Images
          </label>
      
      </form>  
        <div class="board">
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <button class="button">Play</button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="message"></h1>
    </div>
```

#### Example 2: Add click event to button and delete event code for radio buttons

```js
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
const button = document.querySelector('#play-button');
const message = document.querySelector('.message');
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.check');
const numbers = document.querySelector('#numbers');
const images = document.querySelector('#images');

// Changed the two functions below
button.addEventListener('click', function (e){
    // Prevent normal button click events
    e.preventDefault();

    if (numbers.checked) {
       randomNumbers();
    } else {
       randomNumbers2();
    }
 });


function randomNumbers() {
    let arr = [];
    for (number of card){
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        number.innerHTML = random;
        arr.push(number.textContent);   
    }
    //transforming the array into array of card
    let arr2 = arr.map(function(num) {
        return parseInt(num, 10);
      });
   
    const allEqual = arr => arr.every( num => num === arr[0] )
    if(allEqual(arr2)){
        result = message.innerHTML = "YOU WON!";
        message.classList.remove("lost");
        message.classList.add("won"); 
    }else{
        result = message.innerHTML = "YOU LOST!";
        message.classList.add("lost");
        message.classList.remove("won");
    }
    
}


function randomNumbers2() {
  let arr3 = [];

  for (number of card){
    let img_arr = ['https://img1.looper.com/img/gallery/captain-americas-mcu-story-explained/intro-1566320977.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/2QFZ9Ld.jpg', 'https://images.alphacoders.com/102/thumb-1920-1026220.jpg']
   
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    let img =  '<img src="' +img_arr[random] + '" alt = "">';
    number.innerHTML = img
    arr3.push(number.innerHTML);   
}

const allEqual = arr => arr.every( num => num === arr[0] )
    if(allEqual(arr3)){
        result = message.innerHTML = "YOU WON!";
        message.classList.remove("lost");
        message.classList.add("won"); 
    }else{
        result = message.innerHTML = "YOU LOST!";
        message.classList.add("lost");
        message.classList.remove("won");
    }
}
```

```css
.container{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.card{
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border: 1px solid rgb(206, 21, 21);
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
}
.board{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.board button {
    padding: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(0, 162, 255);
    color: whitesmoke;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.message{
    text-align: center;
    top: 20%;
}

.lost{
    color: red;
}

.won{
    color: green;
}

form{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

form  label{
    margin-right: 15px;
}

img{
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <form>
          <label>
            <input class="check" id="numbers" type="radio" name="game">Numbers
          </label>
          <label>
            <input class="check" id="images" type="radio" name="game">Images
          </label>
      
      </form>  
        <div class="board">
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <button class="button" id="play-button">Play</button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="message"></h1>
    </div>
```